# How Can I export/source/. from mate -e?

Tags: linux, terminal, mate

I'm trying to write a simple script that starts a terminal and runs the command `workon foo`.  In other words, I just want to do:

```
mate-terminal -e workon foo
```

However, that doesn't work because the `workon` command requires me to first do:

```
export WORKON_HOME=~/work;
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Normally those lines are run automatically because they're in my `.bashrc`, but evidently `mate-terminal -e` doesn't do a `source ~/.bashrc`.  However, if I try adding those lines to my script:

```
mate-terminal -e export WORKON_HOME=~/work; source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh; workon foo
```

it doesn't work either. MATE tells me:

```
There was an error creating the child process for this terminal
Failed to execute child process "export" (No such file or directory)
```

I have the same problem if I skip the `export` and just do `mate-terminal -e source ...` or if I try to use `.` instead of `source` (`mate-terminal -e . ...`).

I'm not sure how I can load anything if I can't, `export`, `source`, or `.`, but there must be some way because `mate-terminal -e` would be almost useless without it.

Does anyone know how I can I setup my environment in a terminal started with `mate-terminal -e`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have a version installed of `mate-terminal`, but if it works similarly to `gnome-terminal` you can try one of this ways:

- to write directly something like
  <strike>`mate-terminal -e bash -c 'WORKON_HOME=$HOME/work; source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh; workon foo'`</strike> 
  or
  `mate-terminal -e "bash -c 'WORKON_HOME=$HOME/work; source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh; workon foo; read line'"`

  (to  be honest in `gnome-terminal` you should use `-x` instead of `-e`).
- To create your executable script (named `WorkOnScript.sh`, with `chmod u+x WorkOnScript.sh`)

  ```
  #!/bin/bash 
  WORKON_HOME=$HOME/work;
  source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
  cd $HOME/work                                          # If needed
  workon foo
  sleep 10s         # to add  a pause before script and terminal end
  read line         # to wait you press return to close the terminal
  ```

  and to try to execute it with

  ```
   mate-terminal -e /path/to/WorkOnScript.sh
  ```

  or

  ```
   mate-terminal -e "/bin/bash -c \"/path/to/WorkOnScript.sh\""
  ```

**Note**

It is possible to keep the terminal open adding as last command in the string passed to `bash -c`  or as last line of the script:

- for some seconds (or hours...) adding `sleep 10s` (or sleep 10h).
- until is pressed <kbd>return</kbd> adding `read line`
- until <kbd><kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd></kbd> or <kbd>exit</kbd> is pressed adding `/bin/bash` (it executes a shell).

With some terminal via [parameter specification](https://askubuntu.com/a/46630/196535) it possible to keep it open after the execution of the commands. With mate-terminal you can try to see what is interesting from `mate-terminal --help-all`. After that you [have created a profile](https://askubuntu.com/a/46630/196535) with *"Hold the terminal"* checked you can invoke the terminal with the option `--window-with-profile=PROFILENAME` or `--tab-with-profile=PROFILENAME`

**References**

- Man pages of [mate-terminal](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man1/mate-terminal.1.html).
- Other answer about [*how to keep open a terminal*](https://askubuntu.com/a/46630/196535) on the net.

Comment: When I try the first version you provided I got `Failed to parse arguments: Unknown option -c`.  So I then tried the second version, and it worked great ... for about 1ms; after that the terminal closed (presumably because the command is finished).  So then I tried the script form, and tried executing it both ways you suggested, but it had the same problem (ie. the terminal closed immediately).  If you have any suggestions as to how I can fix the terminal-closing-issue I'll happily accept this answer.

Comment: @machineghost: To avoid the _1ms effect_ you can put as last line of your script a `read line` (or a `sleep 10s`) so that the script will wait you press return to end, (or 10 seconds). You can use the same trick after your command in the string of the _bash_ command `...; workon foo; read line ...`.  In general for many terminal it is possible, [see here for example (+)](http://askubuntu.com/a/46630/196535), to give a  parameter to keep open the terminal. In _mate-terminal_ you can use the profile one ` --window-with-profile` after that you created one as suggested above (+).

Comment: Quick note: I also got a "No module named virtualenvwrapper virtualenvwrapper.sh" error, but I fixed it with the answer found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29486113/problems-with-python-and-virtualenvwrapper-after-updating-no-module-named-virtu

Answer (score 2):

How about you run it in a script?

so create your script:

```
touch ~/myscript.sh
chmod 700 ~/myscript.sh
vi ~/myscript.sh
```

then edit it to what you want it to do. 
In vi use **i** to insert and be careful of using backspace,use **ESC** then **X** to delete. Then do **ESC** and then **!qw** to save and exit:

```
#!/bin/bash
export WORKON_HOME=~/work;
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
mate-terminal -e workon foo
```

then try and run it:

```
./myscript.sh
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately that approach doesn't work.  When I run myscript I get `No module named virtualenvwrapper
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.`  I guess the `source` command in the script doesn't carry over to the new `mate-terminal` session :(